# withstand voltage of AC DC power module

Tags: power-supply, voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, ac-dc

i read the datasheet of irm=20-5 which is a AC DC power module it takes a input of voltage of 85-305VAC
and converts into 5V DC at output ,in the datasheet it is written that the withstand voltage is 3KVAC like i can apply a input voltage of 3KVAC ,will it damage the component.
**Datasheet**: https://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=682
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally no. A 3 kVAC input across the input AC terminals will be applied directly to the filter, rectifier, and input-side switching/control circuitry, almost certainly causing damage.

The 3 kVAC rating is given for the insulation between input and output sides ("I/P-O/P"), meaning that the device is rated to not fail when 3 kVAC is applied across its input/output isolation boundary (i.e. the transformer and feedback optoisolator) while the line-neutral or line-line input voltage is within the 85-305 VAC range.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define "fail", but I always thought the withstand voltage was only the guarantee not to leak or conduct at that value.

Comment: @Aaron I was under the impression that the device was expected to *operate* without leakage or failure (of the insulation or other components) \at that value. It doesn't help that this datasheet is a little bit sparse on operating conditions beyond that withstand voltage.